# MongoDB aggregation filter based on max value

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

Suppose I have a document structure where one of the fields, `X`, is an array av objects as shown below.

```
"X" : [ 
    {
      "A" : "abc",
      "B" : 123
    },
    {
      "A" : "wer",
      "B" : 124
    },
    {
      "A" : "fgh",
      "B" : 124
    }
]
```

How can I project only the document where field `B` has the highest values? And if the maximum value is shared by several documents, I just want to return one of them (not important which one). In this case the result could look like:

```
"X" : [ 
    {
      "A" : "wer",
      "B" : 124
    }
]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about this one:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
   {
      $set: {
         X: {
            $filter: {
               input: "$X",
               cond: { $eq: ["$$this.B", { $max: "$X.B" }] }
            }
         }
      }
   },
   { $set: { X: { $arrayElemAt: ["$X", 0] } } }
])
```

Comment: This produces the error `"Unrecognized pipeline stage name: '$set'"`.

Comment: $set is new in 4.2. Try $addField instead

Comment: Yeah I figured, ended up doing that. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can use [$reduce](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/reduce/index.html)

```
  db.collection.aggregate([
      {
        "$project": {
          "X": {
            $reduce: {
              input: "$X",
              initialValue: {},
              in: {
                $cond: [ { "$gt": [ "$$this.B", "$$value.B" ]}, // Condition Check
                  "$$this",      // If condition true ($$this - Current Object)  
                  "$$value"      // If condition false $$value - Previous Returned Object
                ]
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    ])
```

[Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/JdRQo2Oe_Ve)

Answer (score 0):

Updated answer:

Another option that results in the full object being returned at the end:

```
    [
    {$unwind: {
      path: "$X"
    }}, 
    {$sort: {
      "X.B": -1
    }}, 
    {$group: {
      _id: { _id: "$_id"},
      X: {
        $first: "$X"
      }
    }}]
```

Original answer:

You can use the $max operator (https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/max/).

```
    [{$project: {
      X: {$max: "$X.B"}
    }}]
```

Comment: Have a look on this Url - https://mongoplayground.net/p/0wu_q4kjYjo

Comment: This sorts by `A` - you get `{A: "wer", B: 124}` because of `A: "wer"`, not due to `B: 124`

Comment: I think you'd want to change that to `X: {$max: "$X.B"}`. In any case, this will only return the maximum value. I want the whole object to be returned.

Comment: Good catch. Updated to be "$X.B".  As you pointed out, that only returns the maximum value and not the entire object.